# uiwebview take screen shots ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uikit, screenshot

I load a web view with an online Microsoft word document, say of 46 pages. I need to show the pages as thumbnails for user convenience. 
What i do is i take screen shots for each thumbnail of uiWebView by changing offset for each page.
Here is the code

```
-(void)takeScreenShotFromWebViewWithStartOffset:(int)currentOffset andEndOffset:(int)endOffset
{
// noOfScreenShotsInOneGo is 10 , i take load thumbnails lazily. first load 10 and when user scrols to the last row of the horizontal table view i load next 10 and so on.

       for (int screenshot= 0; screenshot<noOfScreenShotsInOneGo; screenshot++) {
        [[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, currentOffset)];
        if(currentOffset<endOffset)
        {
            currentOffset = currentOffset+480; // 480 is the screen height


        UIImage *img = [self takeScreenShotFromView:webView withWidth:320 andHeight:480];
        [self.thumbnailsArray addObject:img];
        }
    }


}


+ (UIImage *) takeScreenShotFromView: (UIWebView *) webview withWidth: (float)width andHeight: (float)height
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    [webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    img = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToWidth:60];
    return img;
}

+(UIImage*)imageWithImage: (UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
    float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"imageWidth:%f height:%f",newImage.size.width,newImage.size.height);
    return newImage;
}
```

I call this method from a loop and get 10 thumbnails (each time i add page height to content offset) , and display them in the horizontal table view in the bottom of the screen.

This code works fine on ipod 5 with ios 6 and 7 , but on ipod touch 4 application crashes (with memory warning) while running the code. But if i take several screen shots, with same content offset , it works fine. At the result of this only first page image is shown for all the thumbnails. What i think is there is some issue in take screen shot , then change offset of webview and then take screen shot (so on) method. 
Please help me either the technique to create thumbnails is  wrong? Or memory foot print increase so much that OS decides to kill the app?

Comment: do you need to support ios 6?

Comment: Show the code in `imageWithImage:scaledToWidth:` method.

Comment: @Amar i added more code and explanation.